# How to join two collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections INFODOCS and SETTINGS.
Based on the values stored in SETTINGS, I want to find which documents are HIGH priority in INFODOCS.
If ML_SCORE <= HIGH_PRIORITY, document in INFODOC is classified as HIGH Prio doc.
The join condition for these two collections is INFODOCS.COMPONENT = SETTINGS._id

INFODOCS

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "COMPONENT": "ABC",
    "ML_SCORE": 0.45,
    "PROCESSOR_ID" : "12345"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "COMPONENT": "ABC",
    "ML_SCORE": 0.25,
    "PROCESSOR_ID" : "12345"
  }
]
```

SETTINGS

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "ABC",
    "HIGH_PRIORITY": 0.40,
    "MEDIUM_PRIORITY": 0.55
  }
]
```

I have tried the below aggregation pipeline.
Here the problem is, I have to merge the output of $lookup to main cluster and then match the condition.
I was wondering if there is much efficient way of achieving the same.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            '$match': {
                'PROCESSOR_ID': userid
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'SETTINGS',
                'localField': 'COMPONENT',
                'foreignField': '_id',
                'as': 'RESULT'
            }
        },
        {
            '$replaceRoot': {
                'newRoot': { '$mergeObjects': [{ '$arrayElemAt': ['$RESULT', 0] }, '$$ROOT'] }
            }
        },
        {
            '$match': {
                '$expr': { '$lte': ['$ML_SCORE', '$HIGH_PRIORITY'] }
            }
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                'RESULT': 0
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Please use correct terms. A "cluster" is not a "collection", see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/databases-and-collections/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$lookup` with pipeline (as you can see in this answer) to reduce the amount of transferred data. Another approach (if you expect very few `INFODOCS` to match) is to start from the `SETTINGS`, which will perform this search only once:

```
db.SETTINGS.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "INFODOCS",
      let: {highP: "$HIGH_PRIORITY", pId: "12345"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {$eq: ["$PROCESSOR_ID", "$$pId"]},
                {$lte: ["$ML_SCORE", "$$highP"]}
              ]
            }
        }}
      ],
      as: "comp"
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$comp"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$comp", "$$ROOT"]}}},
  {$unset: "comp"}
])
```